# How to set Editor Background Color in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, settings

Looked for like half an hour.
Their online documentation is out of date.
Terrible documentation for the simplest things to do with PhpStorm!

And the interface for making such changes - is in no way intuitive.

Try complaining to them - they couldn't care any less.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Setting location as of this answer - Jan 01 - 2018:

**File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->General->Text->Default text**

PHPStorm has tones of people looking for these types of answers - and very old answers pointing everyone in the wrong direction. This is where I found the particular setting location today.

They also provide a shortcut for finding the particular area where the settings would apply to the code that you are currently editing:

"***However, it may not be apparent where the color of this or that element comes from. This is why we came up with the Jump to Colors and Fonts action. To use this, place the caret on any element in your code, press Double Shift (Search Everywhere), and find the Jump to Colors & Fonts item.***"

- place the caret on any element in your code
- press Double Shift
- Search Everywhere should pop up
- List item
- the Jump to Colors & Fonts item

This should take you to the setting area that has the particular color where your caret was in your code at the time.

Comment: *"As of Jan 01 - 2018"* It has been like that for the last 2 major versions. before that the "Color Scheme" was called "Colors & Fonts" for a long time.

Comment: Exactly - so I am mentioning the date, so that anyone reading it will know when the answer found the setting in this location. The problem is - there are tones of documents out there giving the old answer. And those old answers do NOT have a date associated with the location of the setting at the time. So maybe people want to find the correct answer - instead of a half hour of wrong answers - and they would be reassured by the date mentioned with the answer?

Comment: So .. as I understand ... the main problem was in the "Color Scheme" vs "Colros & Fonts" ... or something else? Because if it's the *only reason* (the aforementioned "vs" part) .. then I *personally* do not see a big problem here -- for me such substitution was quite obvious (they used "color scheme" wording all this time before and now changed the Settings section name). Surely, if you are brand new user then you will be confused by the amount of settings available and the fact that the path mentioned in some answer does not actually exist...

Comment: Also https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/08/jump-to-colors-and-fonts-in-phpstorm/

Comment: HAHA! They even admit themselves - as they are adding the (also not so apparent) details of the jump feature "However, it may not be apparent where the color of this or that element comes from" Haha! Man!... that is why I posted this answer / question - everything jetbrains does - as far as customer service and facilitating intuitive use of their software - is indeed laughable. To bury the simple function of changing the font color or backgraound - 8 directories deep - is ridiculous.

Comment: Well glad that's obvious.

Answer (score 4):

*Actual on Dec 02 — 2019*

You should change the background colour in two places:

**File - Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - Language Defaults - Template Language - Background**

**File - Settings - Editor - Color Scheme - General - Text - Default text - Background**

---

If it doesn't help use **Jump to Color and Fonts** from double-shift menu.

It is convenient to copy-paste HEX-code of colour like D2FFD2